# Dequeue set-post-thumbnail.min.js

Tags: javascript, wp-enqueue-script, scripts

Want to alter the behavior how `set-post-thumbnail` works (add additional functionality upon successful set post thumbnail). Looking on how to dequeue the stock `set-post-thumbnail.min.js` script so I can copy it and add my modifications.

Not sure on how to do it though. It is added via `wp_default_scripts`, which is entirely new to me. http://wpseek.com/function/wp_default_scripts/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to dequeue like normal. Despite the complexity of the function, it is really just enqueueing scripts and styles. Tested with the admin bar script on the front end:

```
add_action(
  'wp_enqueue_scripts',
  function() {
    wp_dequeue_script('admin-bar'); 
  }
);
```

You just want `admin_enqueue_scripts` and `set-post-thumbnail`:

```
add_action(
  'admin_enqueue_scripts',
  function() {
    wp_dequeue_script('set-post-thumbnail'); 
  }
);
```

I am not sure of the wisdom of dequeueing a Core script though. Be warned.

Comment: Hm, it's still working. From what I can tell I shouldn't be able to set new featured images without set-post-thumbnail. And that still works (not sure which file the script is put in, it's not enqueued on it's own, so it must be in a common.js or similar).